# How to download several urls into one file

Tags: wget

I have URLs like this.

```
http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000290205346
http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000832812637
http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000853093050
```

After that it should hit the browser. It will get some output like this

```
 404000290205346|9225534526|2|Prepaid|2
 404000832812637|9204506289|2|Prepaid|2
 404000853093050|9247868854|2|Prepaid|2
```

I also tried the following:

```
wget -t 45 -0 log.txt -i input.txt
```

It generates the output in single files but I want all three files in one file.

Answer (score 2):

```
wget -O - http://yourthing/{file1,file2,file3} > output
```

should put it in one file

```
$ cat output
first file
second file
third file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Bash's compound command functionality. The first will invoke all the commands in a subshell with it's own environment:

```
$ ( wget -qO- http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000290205346; \
    wget -qO- http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000832812637; \
    wget -qO- http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000853093050; \
  ) > somefile
```

The second command will invoke the commands in the current shell's environment:

```
$ { wget -qO- http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000290205346; \
    wget -qO- http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000832812637; \
    wget -qO- http://203.90.117.109/wds_cdma/wds.aspx?min=404000853093050; \
  } > somefile
```

I would also use `-qO-` instead of just `-O-`. This tells `wget` to be quiet with its output.